# Correct construction of the sentence "Marcs computer"

Tags: sentence-construction, names

How could I write sentence below in two words:

> **Original:** "*The computer from Marc* is damaged."
>
> **With less words:** "*Marcs computer* is damaged."

Is this correct and what about the name ends with `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` like Amanda or ending with a `s` like Jesus?

Comment: You need to include the apostrophe - ***Marc's** computer is damaged.*.With some names, such as ***Jesus'** computer*, some people find it too awkward to actually pronounce the final ***s***, so they (quite correctly) omit it from the written form as well, but the apostrophe itself is *always* written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possessive marker suffix -**'s**. I think you know how to use it already, but you misspelled the suffix. The **apostrophe is obligatory when using the possessive suffix.**

All *singular* **possessors** take -'s regardless of ending.

> Roxas's ice cream melted.
>
> Amanda's computer is broken.
>
> Who is looking for Marcus's dog?

Though stuff like "Achilles", "Socrates", "Moses", "Jesus" are controversial due to mismatches in pronunciation and traditions.

*Plural* **possessors** take only the apostrophe except if that plural doesn't end with an S.

> The cats' food has been stolen.
>
> The employees' cake was ruined.

but

> The children's toys were gone.

Answer (score 2):

Your original sentence is a little ambiguous as to ownership of the computer:

> The computer **from** Marc is damaged.

If the computer **belongs to a person** named Marc, then the possessive is used:

> **Marc's** computer is damaged.

If the **brand name** of the computer is Marc or the computer is from a third-party, then the computer doesn't belong to the manufacturer but to someone else:

> The **Marc** computer is damaged.

Either of these two sentences resolves the ambiguity.

Comment: @Peter- Perfect! I'll sleep better now. ;-)

Comment: @MarkHubbard To sleep, perchance to dream... always a good thing!